# Why is my for loop unable to capture "success"?

Tags: python, for-loop, nested-loops, control-flow

I am trying to scan through log files and match certain strings (operators). Once I match the operator, I would liked to look for another string that will specify "success" of a task in a log file. My loop is only working before the first elif..  the variable operator_type is defined correctly. I tested it by printing operator_type.  I don't fully understand using "break" so those maybe the issue.  The code is jumping all the way down to the else (based on my output).

`fl_sts == 'FAILED'`   My code is able to find failures. It is unable to find successes.

```
    for i, line in enumerate(lines):
        if (fl_sts in line):
            end_line = lines[i]
            success_status = fl_sts
            break
        elif operator_type == op_py in line:
            for line in lines:
                if (sc_crt_py in line):
                    end_line = lines[-1]
                    success_status = sc_sts
                else:
                    break
        elif operator_type == op_eml in line:
            for line in lines:
                if (sc_crt_eml in line):
                    end_line = lines[-1]
                    success_status = sc_sts
                else:
                    break
        elif operator_type == op_s3 in line:
            for line in lines:
                if (sc_crt_s3 in line):
                    end_line = lines[-1]
                    success_status = sc_sts
                else:
                    break
        elif operator_type == op_bsh in line:
            for line in lines:
                if (sc_crt_bsh in line):
                    end_line = lines[-1]
                    success_status = sc_sts
                else:
                    break
        elif operator_type == op_snw in line:
            for line in lines:
                if (sc_crt_snw in line):
                    end_line = lines[-1]
                    success_status = sc_sts
                else:
                    break
        elif operator_type == op_snw_sns in line:
            for line in lines:
                if (sc_crt_snw_sns in line):
                    end_line = lines[-1]
                    success_status = sc_sts
                else:
                    break
        else:
            success_status = sc_sts_rn
            end_line = 'None'
```

For example, if operator_type is `(PythonOperator)` the `sc_crt_py` is `'Done. Returned value was: None'`.

A sample line `[2019-07-08 15:06:44,415] {python_operator.py:104} INFO - Done. Returned value was: None`.

Please note `(PythonOperator)` is captured above this loop successfully and `{python_operator}` is noise on the line.

I am expecting an output of `Successful` as `sc_sts = 'Succesful'`

I appreciate insights. I am still learning.

Comment: Can you provide sample input text and expected output?

Comment: @Alderven  I have added some more context. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me. Removing the breaks and changing the elif statements.

```
for i, line in enumerate(lines):
        if (fl_sts in line):
            end_line = lines[i]
            success_status = fl_sts
            break
        elif operator_type == op_py:
            for line in lines:
                if (sc_crt_py in line):
                    end_line = lines[-1]
                    success_status = sc_sts
        elif operator_type == op_eml:
            for line in lines:
                if (sc_crt_eml in line):
                    end_line = lines[-1]
                    success_status = sc_sts
        elif operator_type == op_s3:
            for line in lines:
                if (sc_crt_s3 in line):
                    end_line = lines[-1]
                    success_status = sc_sts
        elif operator_type == op_bsh:
            for line in lines:
                if (sc_crt_bsh in line):
                    end_line = lines[-1]
                    success_status = sc_sts
        elif operator_type == op_snw:
            for line in lines:
                if (sc_crt_snw in line):
                    end_line = lines[-1]
                    success_status = sc_sts
        elif operator_type == op_snw_sns:
            for line in lines:
                if (sc_crt_snw_sns in line):
                    end_line = lines[-1]
                    success_status = sc_sts
        else:
            success_status = sc_sts_rn
            end_line = 'None'
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the breaks, you are exiting the loop after the first If

Comment: Thank you. What should be in the else?

Comment: I don't think you even need an else. Try it without them

Comment: From my understanding, you are looking for an operator, then you keep on reading the file until you reach a specific keyword, is that correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct. I have 5 or 6 different operators, each have a different "Success criteria" ( a string that lets me know a task was successful)..  I removed the "elses" and the loop is going straight into the last else (which states a task is ```Currently Running```)

Answer (score 2):

Your sentiment that you do not understand `break` seems to be correct. `break` *breaks* out of the innermost enclosing for or while loop. It is used to stop the execution of a loop early. I would read through the docs on flow control: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html

Answer (score 0):

```
with open(path, "r") as f:
     started = None
     for line in f.readlines():
         line.strip()
         if started is None:
            if operator in line:
               #Do something here
         else:
            if "success" in line:
               #Do something here
               started = None
            else:
               pass
```

Comment: This will should do the trick, once it finds an operator, will loop constantly until it finds "success" in a line. Else, it will pass and continue the loop. Hope that works for you.

Comment: I am looping through thousands of files.. I am using the open() at the beginning of my script..Let me try it

Comment: Ah I  see, let me know how it goes

Comment: My code is not entering the for loop after looking at operator type.. I printed the operator type before: for line in lines:
                if (sc_crt_py in line):   and it is printing correctly..

Comment: Instead of elif operator_type == op_s3 in line: .. I tried elif operator_type == op_s3 and it worked...

Comment: Glad it worked, can you mark it as resolved if it fixed it? Thanks !

Comment: David, I did not use any of the recommendations on here.